# Compound understanding

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence,
“Doing that allowed me and the people I worked with to **compound** our understanding over time and improve the quality of our collective decision making.”
In Oxford dictionary:[compound](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/compound)

> Verb 1: Make up (a composite whole); constitute.
>   Verb 2:Make (something bad) worse; intensify the negative aspects of.

It does not make sense to say 'make up' or 'constitute' our understanding.

How to understand it?

It's context:

> “I discovered I could do that by expressing my decision-making criteria in the form of algorithms that I could embed into our computers. By running both decision-making systems—i.e., mine in my head and mine in the computer—next to each other, I learned the computer could make better decisions than me because it could process vastly more information than I could, and it could do it faster and unemotionally. Doing that allowed me and the people I worked with to **compound our understanding** over time and improve the quality of our collective decision making. I discovered that such decision-making systems—especially when believability weighted—are incredibly powerful and will soon profoundly change how people around the world make all kinds of decisions. Our principle-driven approach to decision making has not only improved our economic, investment, and management decisions, it has helped us make better decisions in every aspect of our lives.
>   ”
>   Excerpt From: Dalio, Ray. “Principles.”

Comment: "compound (verb): I. To put together, combine, construct, compose." - source: OED(dot)com

Comment: It could also be a figurative use of the word **compound** in the financial sense as in "compounded interest".  Understanding leads to increased understanding, building upon itself.  This is likely given the sentence *Our principle-driven approach to decision making has not only improved our economic, investment, and management decisions...*